# Prove that $x$ is irreducible in $\Bbb C[x,y]/(x^3+y^3-1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

This is from the problem of proving $\Bbb C[x,y]/(x^3+y^3-1)$ is not a UFD. Here is my attempt:

Every polynomial in $\Bbb C[x,y]$ is of the form $$p_1(x)+p_2(x)y+p_3(x)y^2+r(x,y)(x^3+y^3-1)$$ for some polynomials $p_1(x),p_2(x),p_3(x),r(x,y)$ in $\Bbb C[x,y]$. So that given $$x=(p_1(x)+p_2(x)y+p_3(x)y^2)(q_1(x)+q_2(x)y+q_3(x)y^2)+r(x,y)(x^3+y^3-1)$$ one needs to show that either $q_1(x)+q_2(x)y+q_3(x)y^2$ or $p_1(x)+p_2(x)y+p_3(x)y^2$ is a unit modulo $(x^3+y^3-1)$, i.e for example $$(p_1(x)+p_2(x)y+p_3(x)y^2)f(x,y) = k+g(x,y)(x^3+y^3-1)$$ for some constant $k$ and polynomials $f,g\in\Bbb C[x,y]$ is the same as saying $p_1(x)+p_2(x)y+p_3(x)y^2$ is a unit modulo $(x^3+y^3-1)$.

This gets extremely messy afterwards. Is there a better way I could approach this?

Comment: Hint: $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 - 3abc = (a+b+c)(a^2 +b^2 + c^2 - ab-bc -ca)$. So,  if $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 = 0$, then this gives you a way to factorize $3abc$ as something not like $a \times b \times c$, and thus we don't have a UFD.

Comment: By the way, $x^3 = 1-y^3 = (1-y)(1+y+y^2)$...

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist But one needs to prove $x$ is irreducible, which is the difficult part.

Comment: [crossposted](https://mathoverflow.net/q/457911/19965) but probably belongs here.

Comment: Crossposting after only 7 hours without an answer is considered premature.  Maybe after a day or two with no activity one could make a case to crosspost.

Comment: @rschwieb [MO guidelines recommend a week](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5012/can-i-ask-a-question-on-mathoverflow-and-also-on-another-site), fyi.

Comment: @KReiser Sounds even better.